NextAuth Session Status Stuck at "Loading" State
I'm experiencing an issue with NextAuth in my Next.js application. The session status gets stuck at the loading state, and the spinner appears indefinitely in the main navigation bar, but only on the home page.

Setup:
I have a <MainNav /> component in my app, as shown below:
main-nav.tsx
import React from "react"
import Link from "next/link"
import { MainNavItem } from "@/types"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { UserAccountNav } from "@/components/user-account-nav"

interface MainNavProps {
  items?: MainNavItem[]
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

export function MainNav({ items }: MainNavProps) {

  return (
    <div className="flex h-16 items-center px-2.5 py-4 md:px-4">
      {items?.length ? (
        <nav className="ml-6 mr-auto hidden md:block">
          <ul className="flex space-x-4">
            {items.map((item) => (
              <li
                key={item.title}
                className={cn(
                  "nav-link relative z-10 cursor-pointer py-0.5 font-medium text-muted-foreground transition-all hover:text-primary sm:text-sm"
                )}
              >
                <Link href={item.href}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      ) : null}
      <div className="ml-auto flex items-center gap-4">
        <Link
          href="/contact"
          className="text-sm font-medium text-muted-foreground"
        >
          Contact
        </Link>
        <UserAccountNav />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

In the <MainNav />, I render the <UserAccountNav /> component, as shown below:
user-account-nav.tsx
"use client"

import React from "react"
import Link from "next/link"
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons"
import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/user-avatar"

export function UserAccountNav() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  const pathname = usePathname()

  const name = session?.user?.name
  const image = session?.user?.image

  console.log("Auth status: ", status)

  if (status === "loading") {
    return (
      <Icons.loaderCircle className="size-4 animate-spin text-muted-foreground" />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-max space-x-2">
      {status === "authenticated" ? (
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger className="flex items-center space-x-1">
            <UserAvatar
              user={{ name: name || "", image: image || "" }}
              className="size-8"
            />
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-2 p-2">
              <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1 leading-none">
                {session.user.email && (
                  <p className="w-[200px] truncate text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                    {session.user.email}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            {/* Menu items */}
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem
              className="cursor-pointer"
              onSelect={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                signOut({
                  callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/login`,
                })
              }}
            >
              <Icons.logOut className="mr-2 size-4 text-muted-foreground" />
              Sign out
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      ) : (
        // Conditionally render the Login button only if the pathname is not '/login'
        pathname !== "/login" && (
          <Link
            href="/login"
            className={cn(buttonVariants({ size: "sm" }), "rounded-full")}
          >
            Log in
          </Link>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

In the <UserAccountNav /> component:

When the status is loading, I render a loading spinner.
When the status is authenticated, I render a <UserAvatar /> component.
When the status is unauthenticated, I render a Login link.

Here is the <NextAuthProvider /> component:
next-auth-provider.tsx
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

type NextAuthProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export function NextAuthProvider({ children }: NextAuthProviderProps) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
}

And here is the root layout of my app:
/app/layout.tsx
import "@/styles/globals.css"

import { Inter } from "next/font/google"
import NextTopLoader from "nextjs-toploader"

import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster"
import { NextAuthProvider } from "@/components/next-auth-provider"
import { ReactQueryProvider } from "@/components/react-query-provider"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`${inter.className} scroll-smooth`}>
      <body>
        <ReactQueryProvider>
          <NextAuthProvider>
            <NextTopLoader showSpinner={false} color="#2563EB" />
            {children}
            <Toaster />
          </NextAuthProvider>
        </ReactQueryProvider>
      </body>
      <Toaster />
    </html>
  )
}

The Issue:
When I first load the home page, the session status remains in loading state and the spinner in the main nav is displayed indefinitely. To see this in action, visit https://indieaitools.com. In the main nav bar, to the right, you will see a loading spinner. Even if you refresh the page multiple times, you will still see the spinner.
Now, if you visit a different page, the loading status correctly updates. To see this in action, visit https://indieaitools.com/tools?name=MakeAudio, and you will see a Login link in the main nav bar.

Now come back to the home page (by clicking on the Home link in the navbar), and you will see the Login link. The session status updates correctly. So, this problem appears only when I visit the home page for the first time.
Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Version Info:

next: 14.1.3
next-auth: ^4.24.5

Here is the code for my home page:
import { getAiTools } from "@/lib/get-ai-tools"
import { ToolCard } from "@/components/tool-card"

export default async function Home() {
  const aiTools = await getAiTools()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="mb-2 text-center text-primary">INDIE AI TOOLS</h1>
      <p className="mb-16 text-center">AI Tools by Indie Hackers</p>
      <div className="container mx-auto grid max-w-5xl gap-4 sm:grid-cols-4">
        {aiTools.map((tool) => (
          <ToolCard key={tool.name} tool={tool} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Here is the <ToolCard /> component:
import Link from "next/link"

import { Bookmark } from "@/components/bookmark"
import { ToolStats } from "@/components/tool-stats"

type ToolCardProps = {
  tool: {
    name: string
    url: string
    primaryCategory: string
    pricingModel: string
  }
}

export function ToolCard({ tool }: ToolCardProps) {

  return (
    <div className="relative min-w-24 rounded-md border bg-slate-50 shadow transition-all hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg">
      <div className="grid p-3">
        <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold">{tool.name}</h2>
        <p className="mb-3 text-xs">{new URL(tool.url).hostname}</p>
        <p className="text-sm font-medium text-foreground">
          {tool.primaryCategory}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between rounded-b-md border-t px-3 py-2 text-xs text-muted-foreground">
        <p>{tool.pricingModel}</p>
        <ToolStats toolName={tool.name} />
      </div>
      <Link
        className="absolute inset-0"
        href={`/tools?name=${encodeURIComponent(tool.name)}`}
      >
        <span className="sr-only">View details</span>
      </Link>
      <Bookmark toolName={tool.name} />
    </div>
  )
}

Here is the <ToolStats /> component:
"use client"

import { FaRegComment } from "react-icons/fa"
import { IoBookmarkOutline } from "react-icons/io5"

import { useTotalBookmarksCount } from "@/hooks/use-total-bookmarks-count"
import { useTotalUserReviewsCount } from "@/hooks/use-total-user-reviews-count"

type ToolStatsProps = {
  toolName: string
}

export function ToolStats({ toolName }: ToolStatsProps) {
  const totalReviewsCount = useTotalUserReviewsCount(toolName)
  const totalBookmarksCount = useTotalBookmarksCount(toolName)

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
        <IoBookmarkOutline />
        <span>{totalBookmarksCount}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
        <FaRegComment />
        <span>{totalReviewsCount}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}



Can you show the content of your _app.tsx file?

@codejockie Added the code for the home page. By the way I am using app router.

I don't see the code for _app.tsx. If you don't have that file, you are probably using the default. In that case, you would need to create it. Refer to the documentation on Next.js site for that. When you have done that, you should move your SessionProvider to that file.

@codejockie I have already wrapped my app with NextAuthProvider in the root layout of my app. So, that's not the issue here.
